# Module's function is not being copied

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, circular-dependency

I have defined a function in a module named server.js and want to use it in sign-in.js. server.js exports only one function-emailExists.

```
module.exports.emailExists = emailExists;
```

So I import it using:

```
const server = require("./../server");
```

and wish to use as

```
const emailExists = server.emailExists;// but emailExists is undefined
console.log("emailExists is ", typeof emailExists);// result undefined
```

but
the below is working as expected

```
console.log("server.emailExists is ", typeof server.emailExists); // returns function
```

I thought maybe functions are not copied or referenced, but the below code works as i want the above example to work

```
//this works as expected
    function x() {
      console.log("from x");
    }
    const y = x;
    console.log("y is", typeof y); // logs y is function
    y(); // returns "from x"
```

I am not sure whether the difference in these two examples is  because in first case function is being copied/ referenced from another module and in the second case, function from the same file is bieng copied/ referenced, as few days ago i created new project just to check this and fuction from other module was being copied, i.e. the below was working.

```
const y= require("./mod2.js").x //x is function in mod2
console.log(typeof y)// returned fucntion
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const db = require("./server/database/index.js");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const router = require("./routes/sign-in.js");

app.use(express.static("./"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
});

const upload = multer();

let OTP;

app.post("/sendOTP", upload.none(), async (req, res) => {
  OTP = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000);

  http
    .get(
      `http://myactualdomain.com:portthatiamusing/${OTP}/${req.body.email}`,
      async (response) => {
        console.log("got response from linux server");
        let existingEmail = await emailExists(req.body.email);
        if (existingEmail === true) {
          res.json(existingEmail);
        } else if (existingEmail === false) {
          res.json(existingEmail);
        } else {
          res.json(await emailExists(req.body.email));
        }
      }
    )
    .on("error", (err) => {
      res.json({ err });
    });
});

async function emailExists(email) {
  let sqlResponse = await db
    .emailExists(email)
    .then((data) => {
      if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
        return { exists: false };
      } else {
        return { exists: true };
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error("Error which checking if Email exists in MySQL");
    });
  return JSON.parse(sqlResponse.exists);
}

app.use(
  "/",
  (req, res, next) => {
    req.OTP = OTP;
    next();
  },
  router()
);

app.listen(PORT);

module.exports.emailExists = emailExists;
```

sign-in.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();
const db = require("../server/database/index.js");
const server = require("./../server");
const validateOTP = require("./validateOTP.js");
const emailExists = server.emailExists;

module.exports = () => {
  router.use("/validateOTP", validateOTP());

  router.post("/sign-in", upload.none(), async (req, res) => {
    if (await server.emailExists(req.body.email)) {
      let correctPassword = await db
        .retreivePassword(req.body.email)
        .then((password) => {
          if (password[0].password === req.body.password) {
            res.json({ successful: true });
          } else {
            res.json({ successful: false });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.json(err);
          throw "Error checking password from MySql";
        });
    } else {
      res.json({ successful: "email doesn't exist" });
    }
    //this works as expected
    console.log("server.emailExists is ", typeof server.emailExists);
    //this does not works as expected. expeted value function, actual value undefined
    console.log("emailExists is ", typeof emailExists);

    //this works as expected
    function x() {
      console.log("from x");
    }
    const y = x;
    console.log("y is", typeof y); // logs y is function
    y(); // returns "from x"
  });
  return router;
};
```

Comment: Circular dependencies. Step through them with a debugger to see that you're accessing the property before assigning it to the exports object.

Comment: Thanks, issue was probably due to circular dependencies